# Generalizations of linear groups

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, finitely-generated, linear-groups

There are quite many general results about finitely generated linear groups (e.g. the Malcev theorem that they are residually finite, the Tits alternative for them, etc.). Since at least in the real case these are just groups that act faithfully on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by continuous automorphisms, I wonder whether similar questions have been considered when one replaces $\mathbb{R}^n$ by some slightly more complicated Lie group.

So more precisely, the question is: Let $G$ be a real Lie group and let $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ be the group of its continuous automorphisms. Let $\Gamma$ be a finitely generated group and suppose there is an injective homomorphism $\Gamma\to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$. Can something general be said about $\Gamma$ for specific $G$ (besides $\mathbb{R}^n$, say when $G$ is the Heisenberg group)?

Comment: You don't quantify on $n$, which hides the difference. Linear groups are those embedding in $\mathrm{GL}_n$ for *some* $n$. Studying those for fixed $n$ is a much more specific question (e.g., all finite groups embed in $\mathrm{GL}_n$, while the question of which finite groups embed into given $\mathrm{GL}_n$ is non-trivial).

Comment: You probably want $G$ connected, since every discrete group is a 0-dimensional Lie group. If $G$ is a connected Lie group, $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is linear (as it embeds naturally into $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$. So "embedding into $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ for some connected Lie group $G$ is the same as being linear.

Comment: For your specific case, yes, one knows what Aut of the Heisenberg group is (over the reals this is some semidirect product $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{R})\ltimes\mathbf{R}^2$, the action being the standard one twisted by some character). So one can say plenty of things about groups mapping therein.

Comment: @YCor Thanks, I see my question was not really meaningful. Embeddings into $\mathrm{GL}_n$, for some $n$, is already the most general representation I had in mind. So there is probably nothing to add - unless some of these more restrictive linear representations (into automorphism groups of some particular class of connected Lie groups) have been studied?

Comment: Yes, spaces of representations of given groups (e.g. surface groups) into general reductive groups have been studied. Also the existence of a faithful representation in low dimension (such as $\mathrm{SL}_2$) can be used.